# jQuery - stop form submission from changing page using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit a form without reloading the page. I have tried using this script with no success:

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'serverSide.php',
        data: $('#formId').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can return false. You could also remove the `action` attribute from the `form` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using return false will usually do the trick

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'serverSide.php',
      data: $('#formId').serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't go to the php page now, but it does refresh. How do I stop that happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting preventDefault before the AJAX. This way the default actions are prevented *before* the ajax-request is triggered

```
$('#formId').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'serverSide.php',
        data: $('#formId').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't go to the php page now, but it does refresh. How do I stop that happening?